# Can we able to send messages on whats app through C# application without any third party tool?

Tags: c#, .net, whatsapp, whatsapi

I want to send whatsapp messages through c# program. I found out there are different gateway through which we can send messages from c# to whatsapp. but I want to create my own program through which we can send messages to whatsapp. Is it possible?
is there any guidelines for that?

Comment: Try exploring APIs offered by whatsapp https://blog.cloudrail.com/whatsapp-api-how-to-use-the-whatsapp-chat-api/

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for you answer but cloudrail is not supporting whatsapp...

Comment: See [Why doesn't WhatsApp have an API?](https://www.quora.com/WhatsApp-Why-doesnt-WhatsApp-have-an-API). Looks like the answer is no, but you will need to do more research.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this package on your project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WhatsAppAPI/

Go through the video for better understanding.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7LedIO47Yw

Comment: I want to do this think using my own code not any third party library

Comment: explore their API. Implement their API in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check official WhatsApp Business API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp

After completing the registration process you can send messages in defined templates i.e. you first need to define the templates and then send the messages based on these messages.